# How to or can we use Hu moment to change the shape and width of the object using opencv in python

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I am using face_landmark_dtection model to find the different landmarks of the face. i successfully find the all landmarks and exact location of the landmarks.

Now i want to change the lips position like i want to open the lips for this purpose i store the the upper lips and lower lips landmark position in a list and using this list i get the centroid of both lips using

`M = cv2.moments(thresh)`

and pass the points to the huMoments = cv2.HuMoments(M) to get the hu moments 7 points.
i want to use these 7 points to change the lips style and position like for open mouth and close mouth can it possible or if possible how i use these points to change lips shape or there is another option for this purpose.

Thanks in advance ..